# how to register a .net dll not being used as a com interop in vb6?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6

I have a .net .dll written in c# and not being used as a COM interop.I need to use this dll as a reference in vb6.I got an error while adding the refrence "Can't add a reference to the specified file"?

By using command promt for registering i got an error " The module was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that it is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again."

Comment: If the .net dll is not exposing a com interop, then by definition you cannot register it.

Comment: Then how to use that dll in vb6? @MarkL

Comment: You can't just take any old .NET assembly and expect to register it for COM.

Comment: @ MickyD Are you sure? we can't access the dll in vb6 without registering COM interop?

Comment: Vb6 uses StdCall convention for calling a library, c# isn't my area of expertise but I don't think c# supports StdCall. So you can either create the c# dll with a com interop (if this is your dll), or you could create an intermediate layer in VB.net or c++ exposing either a com interop or a StdCall interface, or create a c# intermediate with a com interop.

Comment: how to access the .net dll without registering COM interop in vb6? @MarkL

Comment: Your .NET code has to be `[ComVisible(true)]` either on the interface or class.  Then you have to regasm it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly do what you are asking. The only thing that VB6 can "register" is by definition a COM DLL.

If you are not able to modify the C# DLL to add COM interface elements, then alternatively you could write a wrapper in C# or VB (.net) which itself exposes a COM interface, and internally calls the original DLL.